# Device malfunction probability in gamma distribution

Tags: probability, matlab, gamma-distribution

> Lets say that there's a device, which contains 2 consumable
>   components. When the first component fails, the second is started
>   automatically. When both have failed, someone has to change the
>   components. All components are the same. Their uptime follows a gamma
>   distribution with:
>
> Mean $\mu$ = 2700 hours
>
> Sigma $\sigma$ = 400 hours
>
> **What's the probability that both components break at earliest after 6000 hours?**

**My attempt:** I thought that this must be solved by using the Erlang distribution (how many events occur in the given time). I tried converting the parameters from gamma to erlang format:

Variance $\sigma^2 = (400)^2 = 160000$ hours ??

$\mu = \alpha\beta$

$\alpha = \mu/\beta$

$\sigma^2=\alpha\beta^2$

$(\mu/\beta)\beta^2=\mu\beta$

$\beta = \sigma^2/\mu = 400^2/2700 = 1600/27$

According to gamma formula, the value of $\alpha=\mu/\beta$, but in Erlang we should use $\alpha$=n=2 (count of broken components), right?

```
Y ~ erlang(t; n, β) ~ gamma(t; n, β)

P(Y > 6000)
= 1 - P(Y <= 6000)
= 1 - Gamma(6000; n, β)
= 1 - gamcdf(6000, n, β)            // Run in Matlab
= 1 - gamcdf(6000, 2, (1600/27))
```

This however, results in probability of 0. Is this the correct way to calculate the probability?

Comment: it is probably a matter of providing the erlang distribution function in matlab with the arguments in the correct order. Not sure where $\alpha = \beta = 2$ is coming from!

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst it's the number of events/broken components within the given time